# Задачка JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Задать числовое значение переменной `n` при помощи функции `prompt()`. Используя `continue`, вычислить сумму всех положительных непарных чисел, меньших чем `n` и вывести в консоль каждое такое значение. Если на определенном этапе сумма будет равна `25`, то прекратить суммирование.

Мой вариант:

```
var n = +prompt('Enter your number?','');

var i = 0;

var sum = 0;

while(i < n) {  

    if(( i % 2 ) != 0){

        sum += i;

        if(sum > 25){

            break;

        }       

    } else {

        continue;

    }

    console.log(sum);
    i++;

}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста,что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из-за `continue` цикл начинается с начала и переменная `i` не увеличивается.

Получается "мертвый цикл" И случается это на втором шаге. `i` становится равным 1 - это нечетное число - для условия отрабатывает ветка с `continue` и управление переходит к началу цикла.

Решением проблемы может быть перенос `i++` в начало цикла - перед `if`

Answer (score 0):

В задаче написано, что сумма не должна быть равна 25. А в вашем варианте она будет не больше 25.

```
var n = +prompt('Enter your number?','');
for(var i=0, sum=0; i<n && sum!=25; i++, sum += i%2 ? i : 0, console.log(sum)) continue;
```

А еще непарные по русски нечетными называются.